# Como convertir String a Date MySQL en Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hola tengo una duda de cómo es la mejor manera de convertir un string a date en android

```
fechauso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_fechadeuso);
String fechausoo = fechauso.getText().toString();
```

Lo quiero convertir a date porque así como lo tengo al momento de guardarlo en una base de datos mysql en un campo de tipo Date, me lo guarda asi:

> 0000-00-00

Lo estoy intentando resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
String newfecha = fechauso.getText().toString();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date fecha = sdf.parse(newfecha);
        } catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fecha_prestamo",newfecha.trim()));
```

pero me marca el siguiente error:

```
Incopatible types:
Required: java.sql.Date;
Found: java.util.Date
```

importe de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

pero aun asi sigue marcando el error, les ofresco disculpas si estoy preguntando algo muy basico, pero enserio que ando perdido...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este sería un ejemplo para convertir un `String` a `Date`, usando las clases: 

`import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;`

```
  try {
    String stringDate = "Junio 8, 2016";
    Locale espanol = new Locale("es", "ES");
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", espanol);
    Date date = format.parse(stringDate); //Obtienes el String como Date.
    Log.i("INFO", date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

debes tener en cuenta que de entrada debes tener un `String` conteniendo el texto en un formato que pueda convertirse a `Date`.

Otra forma puede ser simplemente, sin hacer uso de [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
  String stringDate= "Junio 8, 2016";
  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
  Date date = format.parse(stringDate);
```

**Actualización:**
Me parece que esta pregunta se quedo "corta", lo que necesitas no es únicamente convertir: "String a Date en Android", lo que necesitas es, en base a un texto de fecha introducido en un EditText, cambiar el formato a otro.
Lo primero que tienes que realizar es definir que formato es el que deben introducir en tu EditText (podrías agregar un validador para asegurar los usuarios no se equivoquen) y definir también el formato que deseas obtener.

en tu caso requieres convertir 
`2016-6-8` a `2016-06-08`
lo podemos realizar de esta forma mediante este método, el cual puedes usar para definir cualquier formato de entrada y de salida:

```
   private static String convierteFecha(String stringFechaEntrada, String formatoEntrada, String formatoSalida){
        Log.i("TAG", "stringFechaEntrada :" +  stringFechaEntrada);
        //Definimos formato del string que ingresamos.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoEntrada);
        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(stringFechaEntrada);
            //Definimos formato del string que deseamos obtener.
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoSalida);
            String stringFechaSalida = sdf.format(date);
            Log.i("TAG", "stringFechaSalida :" +  stringFechaSalida);
             Date dateSalida = sdf.parse(stringFechaSalida);
            //Log.i("TAG", "dateSalida :" +  dateSalida);
            return stringFechaSalida;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Si llamamos el método anterior :

```
 Log.i("INFO : " , convierteFecha("2016-6-8", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

podemos obtener como resultado `2016-06-08`

Con el mismo método puedes cambiar el formato de salida:

```
Log.i("INFO : " , convierteFecha("2016-6-8", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

para obtener `08/06/2016 12:00:00.000`

incluso cambiar el del dato de entrada

```
Log.i("INFO : " , convierteFecha("18 Apr 2012", "dd MMM yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

obteniendo `18/04/2012 12:00:00.000`

Comment: Excelente respuesta , y bastante clara

Comment: Si es muy buena la respuesta y no es que no este clara, si no que al tener muy pocos conocimientos respecto al tema, no lo puedo adaptar a mi problema, ya edite la pregunta con tu solución

Comment: Segun lo que veo estoy tambien estoy teniendo problemas al importar estas librerias, bueno primero intente con la que tu mencionaste y como me marca error intente con la segunda `import java.text.DateFormat; import android.text.format.DateFormat;`

Comment: @Elenasys se quito el error, pero sigue guardando la fecha asi: 0000-00-00, no comprendo que estoy haciendo mal :/

Comment: @GuillermoVargas como tienes definido el formato que el usuario ingresaria para convertiro en Date? Dime un ejemplo del formato a introducir y el formato que deseas.

Comment: @Elenasys en el EditText de tipo Date utilizo un DatePickerDialog emergente, el usuario al seleccionar una fecha del DatePickerDialog quedaria en el EditText: 2016-6-8 y en la base de datos deberia guardar: 2016-06-08

Comment: Ofresco una disculpa, ya funciona, el problema de no guardar las fechas despues de formatearla era debido a que en el archivo php nombre de una manera diferente a las variables, todo lo que tuve que hacer fue dejar la computadora por un rato, ir a tomar un poco de aire, ver un rato la tv y despues al regresar ahi estaba el error y era tan ovbio, muchas gracias por ayudarme @Elenasys

Comment: Vuelvo a disculparme por hacerte escribir el codigo de la actualización de la respuesta aunque no fue envano porque tambien me sera util. Saludos @Elenasys!

Comment: Que bien solucionaste el problema. En cuanto al método considero será útil para otros desarrolladores, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Como yo veo la situación, estas haciendo el parse de manera correcta de String a Date. El error que veo es que necesitas un sql.Date para guardar en tu base de datos el SimpleDateFormat te devuelve un util.Date, la solución sencilla es hacer un parse de util.Date a sql.Date, lo cual sería algo tan sencillo como.

```
java.util.Date miFechaUtil = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); //fecha actual en Util

java.sql.Date miFechaSql = new java.sql.Date(miFechaUtil.getTime()); //Mi fecha Sql..
```

o aun mejor

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", espanol);
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(stringDate).getTime());
```

Ya con tu fecha en sql.Date puedes guardarla en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Anexo captura de mi codigo y colocacion del mismo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]