# Como puedo transformar un String de este formato "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" a Date en Java?

Tags: java, string, date

quiero pasar el siguiente string a Date pero por mas que intento no puedo, saben como podría hacerlo ? El string es el siguiente:

```
String input = "Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 EST 2020";
```

Intento lo siguiente

```
    String input = "Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 EST 2020";
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date date = parser.parse(input);
```

sin embargo me salta el siguiente error
ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 EST 2020"

Comment: _Por más que intento_ no da ninguna pista sobre cómo fueron esos intentos. Puedes [edit] y añadirlos, junto con los errores al ejecutar esos intentos

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13275/como-convertir-string-a-date-mysql-en-android?rq=1

Comment: ya esta editada la pregunta

Comment: Pues más allá de que el 2 de oct de 2020 fue un viernes, correr tu código no genera esa excepción (el parser corrige eso). Aclara de qué paquete estás sacando la clase Date o dale más contexto a la pregunta.

Comment: agrega Locale ´new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.US);´

Comment: @Dramaturgo gracias, me funciono bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 cosas a tener en cuenta:

- La función `parse` puede producir una excepción. En Java es un necesario poner las llamadas que puedan producir excepciones dentro de un try catch.
- `Date` está obsoleto. Considera usar `DateTimeFormatter`, que reporta mejor el problema. La fecha que indicas no es válida.

  El día 2 de octubre no pudo haber caído un día lunes.

  El código es el siguiente:

  ```
  var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
  formatter.parse(input);
  // O para imprimirlo más bonito
  // LocalDateTime.parse(input, formatter);
  ```